# Should we require comments before downvotes?

Tags: feature-request, comments, down-votes

Prompted by the discussion at this [question](https://matheducators.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/17/commenting-when-downvoting), I am making a proposal that we ask StackExchange to require users of Mathematics Educators to comment on a post before they can downvote it.

Upvote the "yes" answer if you agree, upvote the "no" answer if you disagree.  Intermediate answers are welcome too.

Comment: I certainly consider it good from to explain downvotes, but to *enforce* a comment is misguided IMO; and there is already a *suggestion* in place. Consider 1. how would you stop somebody from commenting something that does not indicate they downvoted but still downvoting 2. why have a string of comments if there are multiple downvoters. If anything one could ask for downvotes being public in some way, but AFAIK this got proposed already on meta.SO and got declined (presumably multiple times).

Comment: @quid: To add to this: This is totally against the paradigm of anonymous voting – if there is a downvote and only one comment.

Answer (score 13):

No, we should not ask StackExchange to require users here to comment on a post before they can downvote it.

Comment: I think the noticication already implemented is quite good. Also, maybe someone left already a comment you agree on.

Comment: It may make sense to require new users (maybe < 300 rep) to comment before downvoting. I don't know if this is possible.

Comment: @GammaFunction: That’s already the case: You need 125 reputation (in public betas as well as graduated sites)'

Answer (score 0):

Yes, we should ask StackExchange to require users here to comment on a post before they can downvote it.

Comment: Whoever downvoted this: the point of having two answers is to **upvote** the one you agree with and leave the other be, so that there's an accurate tally of votes.